# Two profiles on development tools (work and home)

Tags: git, bash, macos, npm

I have a scenario like below and I need a solution.

**Scenario**:
I use development tools like Android Package Manager, nodeJS (npm), Homebrew etc. on daily basis. I need to use it at home and at work, but at work I am behind a proxy, so I had to set up the proxy on every single tool, e.g.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy:10
```

But when I work at home, I don't need it, because the proxy doesn't provide the fastest bandwidth in the world:) I'd say, it's pretty slow and I don't want to waste my time to download packages 10 times slower.

**Question**:
Is there any solution to have two different profiles on these tools? Or I need to write a bash script to change these proxy setting every time I change my location (work/home)?

Please let me know, if it's possible or if you had some experiences with a familiar scenario.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all, I ended up with a bash solution I added below:

```
# Proxy
alias proxyChecker='env | grep -i proxy'

function enableProxy() {
    export http_proxy=http://my_proxy.com:port
    export {https,ftp,rsync}_proxy=$http_proxy
    export {HTTP,HTTPS,FTP,RSYNC}_PROXY=$http_proxy
    echo -e  "Proxy environment variable set."

    npm config set proxy $http_proxy
    npm config set https-proxy $http_proxy
    echo -e  "npm proxy set."

    git config --global http.proxy $http_proxy
    git config --global https.proxy $http_proxy
    echo -e  "git global proxy set."
}

function disableProxy() {
    unset {http,https,ftp,rsync}_proxy
    unset {HTTP,HTTPS,FTP,RSYNC}_PROXY
    echo -e  "Proxy environment variable removed."

    npm config delete proxy
    npm config delete https-proxy
    echo -e  "npm proxy removed."

    git config --global --unset http.proxy
    git config --global --unset https.proxy
    echo -e  "git global proxy removed."
}
```

For a reference, there are plenty of good blog posts / articles, e.g. [here](http://blog.marcon.me/post/20217812089/bash-proxy-settings), [here](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Use-a-Proxy-on-the-Linux-Command-Line) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings).

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it now needs a lot of management. It is better to tunnel all your traffic including npm through a SSH tunnel at the OS level. This way you can just turn on/off the tunnel whenever you need it.

There is a nice ssh-tunnel npm package which aids with switching from different environments for staging/prod/etc which you can configure yourself - look at the github repo [here](https://github.com/alternatex/ssh-tunnel).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks promising, but what about e.g. homebrew, tools, like SublimeText or git (when I need to clone a repo for it, I have to set up the proxy too)?

Comment: If you want all your connection to go through a tunnel, then what you need is a VPN, so if your work does not provide one, you can either 1) Get a VPN provider or 2) get a router with VPN support or 3)setup a VPN server like openVPN on a server and that will allow all your connection to go through that VPN, including all your apps. Feel free to raise a new question about that for more info.

Comment: Yeah. I see your point. But the case is to completely bypass using VPN or set up the proxy when I don't need it. Because I can still set up everything behind the proxy and then connect from home through VPN and it works, but it really slow (e.g. 150 kb/s vs 15 MBit/s) and for me it makes a difference. And this is the reason I'm asking about it ;)

Comment: I think you are confused. When you don't need it, you press the switch off button, hopefully you can manage that ;)

Comment: I think after a while that I wasn't confused and you didn't answer to my question ;) However, I really appreciate your help, post, comments and the ssh-tunnel, so I upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: Turn on the VPN when you are doing dev and turn it off when you don't need to. If that doesn't solve it, I hope someone else has a better answer :)